# TCL: concatenating output bits in variable

Tags: tcl

Assume we have a variable 'a' which at the end should represent a value of 4 bits, eg.
a = "0011". The single bits into this variable are read from a VHDL instance.

Lets assume that the first bit of the VHDL output is 1, e.g. result_from_VHDL_instance = 1.
Then I store this most significant bit in my variable a:

```
  set a [BUS2INT result_from_VHDL_instance]; # a = 1
```

Now how do i concatenate to this variable the remaining bits. Assume that the second bit of the VHDL output is again a 1, e.g. result_from_VHDL_instance = 1. I want to concatenate this bit now to the bit that is already stored in a, e.g. a = 11.

And so this continues, for the next bit, eg. result_from_VHDL_instance = 0, the value of a
should be 110 etc.

EDIT:

Thanks for your answers so far, but I think I have a more basic problem here. The first question is whether there is such a datatype in TCL for binary represenation, eg. that a = 1011. If not, then I either have to represent the variable as string or integer, any suggestions for that?

Comment: For the bug to go away just drop the second $ in your command. But its not clear what you really want to do.

Comment: Yes the bug goes away, but I do not get the desired result. I edited my post hope it makes a bit more sense now

Comment: @Patrick, kostix has given the answer to your updated question in his reply.

Answer (score 3):

I would just use a string, appending characters 0 and 1 to it, and then, when the variable had gathered all the input, convert it to a real integer using [binary format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/binary.htm#M5) with the `b*` specifier, like this:

```
set val ""
append val 0
append val 1
...
append val 1
...
set int [binary format b* $val]
# or, in case the digit characters were pushed from the opposite end
set int [binary format b* [string reverse $val]]
```

You can also play games with [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/expr.htm):

```
set val 0
set val [expr {($val << 1) | 0x00}]
...
set val [expr {($val << 1) | 0x01}]
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want:

```
append a [BUS2INT result_from_VHDL_instance]
```

Comment: Given the later edits to the question, I think kostix's answer fits better.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could just do:

```
set a "${a}[BUS2INT result_from_VHDL_instance]"
```